# Git commit history out of sync with file history?

Tags: git

I've been unable to word this question properly, so while I have searched for quite a bit I don't think I really know what I'm asking.

Our team is new to Git and we've encountered behaviour we do not understand. We're starting a brand new project, and right now we just have a Master branch.

Scenario A:

I started the repository and have been making multiple changes to it. A colleague of mine joined the project and cloned the repository. He started working on another area and did not sync up with these changes for several days.

When it came time for him to push his changes, he committed his changes and initiated a pull. This, as expected, pulled down all of my changes. He committed these changes to his local repository as well, then pushed the changes (makes sense).

The commit we see for him on GitHub contains his changes and ALL of my changes (?) over the past several days, making it very difficult to pick out what he changed. Yet, if we check the file history, they do not contain history of this at all. They still reflect the last time I pushed changes.

Scenario B:

Largely the same as above, but another (new) colleague accidentally ignored incoming changes after his commit and pull steps. This was fortunately not as catastrophic as it sounds. The commit history showed this taking place, but the file history did not. My files were essentially 'rolled back' without any indication in the file history, which seems extremely frightening.

I've been doing some reading on how we should be at some point be using a dev branch and having everyone branch off of that and merge back into dev, then probably merge into master when all is said and done. But I guess we don't fundamentally understand what happened in the above scenario.

Edit: I think I may be conceptually imagining what 'pull --rebase' is supposed to do.

Edit 2: Maybe not. Here's what I mean. My colleague and I just tried this out by both creating 'testfile' with different content, then him creating an additional 'testfile2'. When accepting his changes, there was one new file and one merge conflict (as expected). I resolved the one conflict, then committed both his new file and the merged one to my local repository. Then I pushed back to the remote. Why does it show that I added 'testfile2' in my commit when I did not and it already existed?

[Screenshot of commit here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTep1.png)

Comment: Which tool are using to view your commits etc?

Comment: @VenkatNaidu Just using GitHub. The commit history for the repo just seems really bizarre. We only expected it to show the couple of files he added, and instead the commit shows all his files plus all the changes of mine he pulled down.

I'm not sure if we are doing something wrong or this is expected. Either way it's really hard to follow. I imagine there is a better way we should be handling this, it just seems like such a beginner type scenario and we're not sure why it behaves that way.

Comment: Can you provide the github link for your repository otherwise it'll pretty hard to suggest a feasible solution.

Comment: @ckruczek. Can't. The source is not open (GitHub Enterprise). I've edited the original post asking if perhaps this is what 'pull --rebase' is supposed to achieve. I feel like I may be close to answering my own question and this may be the concept of a merge commit versus rebasing before pushing. I will update this post tomorrow once I've tried it. It seems I only ever end up on the right track AFTER asking the question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to lay down some ground rules for using the prod branch. Like you said, ideally you should have another branch for day to day development (master). Each dev should also branch out of master for their feature work, then merge and push their changes.

As to what happened in the scenarios above:

- Scenario 1:

Your colleague should not commit his changes and then pull, he should do it the other way around. This is where a feature branch comes in handy. One good way of doing this is:

1. Pull from master the latest changes
2. Branch off to a new feature branch and do all the work there
3. Check out master
4. Pull the latest changes
5. While on master, merge the feature branch
6. Push the merge commit(s) to remote

Every team have their own way of managing the git lifecycle, but it's generally a good idea to set up rules like these that everyone follows.

- Scenario 2:

I'm assuming by "ignored incoming changes" you mean he force-pushed. That is extremely dangerous, and should be disabled by the remote server if possible. This can (and will) effectively rewrite your history, removing any changes that colleague didn't already have in their remote repo. If you can't disable force pushing or change permissions at the server, one other way of fixing this is write a script that does the fetch/pull/merge/push cycle for you and have everyone use it.

Comment: Thank you for the awesome advice :). I think this is in general a good answer, but I am interested to see why the history appears the way it does in the case above. I've added a second edit with an image showing what I'm talking about. Does what this shows look consistent with what you'd expect?

Comment: Can you explain what you expected? If you're talking about why the first line ("hello Jon...") exists in the right side of the diff, it's because there was an end of file character at the end of the line in the old file, but now there's a new line character at the end of that line, so the line did change.

Comment: I did not create testfile2. yet the commit suggests I did.

Comment: The screenshot doesn't say you added the file, just a line into it. Check the commit message at the top (assuming this it GitHub), it'll give you a list of changed/added/deleted files.

Comment: I did not create testfile2 or add this line to it. There's no record of me changing or creating it in the file history, only the commit history. This happens every time somebody pulls somebody else's changes to sync up before committing and pushing up their own changes. The solution to this seems to be to avoid these scenarios altogether by using different branches as you suggested in your original answer. I was more curious to see why it happens if you are just sharing one branch for every developer, but it's probably not that relevant at this point if there's a solution.